# JFrame moving drawn objects wrap-around on two sides, but not the other two

Tags: java, swing, jframe, drawing

I'm designing a Flocking Simulator. The moving objects on the screen are called Turtles. When the turtles move to the left of top of the JFrame they become stuck, especially in the top-left corner; but when they move past the right/bottom of the screen, the code works correctly and puts the turtle to either the left/top of the JFrame.

The method that performs this "wrapping" is called wrapPosition():

```
public void wrapPosition(double x, double y)
    {
        this.maxX = x;
        this.maxY = y; 

        if(maxX < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("out of bounds X"); //This loop prints the text but does not move the turtle
            this.setPositionX(800);
        }

        if(maxX > 800)
        {
            this.setPositionX(0); //This loop works as expected
        }

        if(maxY < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("out of bounds Y"); //This loop prints the text but does not move the turtle
            this.setPositionY(600);            
        }

        if(maxY > 600)
        {
            this.setPositionY(0); //This loop works as expected
        }        
    }
```

The method wrapPosition() takes as parameter the  X/Y coordinates of the current turtle, and is placed inside a game loop. I have no idea as to why only two of the four if loops setX methods work as expected.

The game loop is as follows:

```
private void gameLoop() 
    {       
        while(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {
                (turtles.get(i)).unDrawTurtle();
                hello.setText("X: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() + "    Y: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY()); //print to JFRAME             
                (turtles.get(i)).wrapPosition((turtles.get(i)).getPositionX(), (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY());                
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {
                (turtles.get(i)).update(1000);              
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
            {               
                (turtles.get(i)).drawTurtle();              
            }

        Utils.pause(deltaTime/2);
        }   
    }
```

Interestingly, the hello.setText code displays the negative coordinates to the screen, but the code designed to amend this does nothing.

If i could have any help, it would be greatly appreciated. Below is a rather large class called turtle that may help? I'm not sure, but ill include it anyway. Cheers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Turtle 
{
    protected Canvas canvas; // private field reference to a canvas private           
    private CartesianCoordinate myLocation, oldLocation; 
    private boolean penDown = true;
    private double angle, minX, minY, maxX, maxY, nowPosX, nowPosY, x, y, a, b, f, g;
    public double d, e, first, second; 
    private int speed, screenWidth, screenHeight;  

    public Turtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation) 
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.myLocation = new CartesianCoordinate(0,0);        
        penDown = true;
        myLocation = initLocation.copy();        
    }

    public String getNumbers(double first, double second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        return("first: " + first + " second: " + second);
    }

    public void wrapPosition(double x, double y)
    {
        this.maxX = x;
        this.maxY = y; 

        if(maxX < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("out of bounds X"); //This loop prints the text but does not move the turtle
            this.setPositionX(800);
        }

        if(maxX > 800)
        {
            this.setPositionX(0); //This loop works as expected
        }

        if(maxY < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("out of bounds Y"); //This loop prints the text but does not move the turtle
            this.setPositionY(600);            
        }

        if(maxY > 600)
        {
            this.setPositionY(0); //This loop works as expected
        }        
    }

    public void cohesian(ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles)
    {
        double flockingDistanceLimit = 20;
        double numberOfFlockers = 0;
        double combinedX = 0;
        double combinedY = 0;
        double averageCombinedX;
        double averageCombinedY;
        //double moveToFlock; 
        //double turnToFlock;     
        double distanceToPotentialFlock;        

        for (DynamicTurtle t : turtles) //SCAN FOR ALL TURTLES
        {
            if(this.getPositionX() != t.getPositionX() && this.getPositionY() != t.getPositionY()) //MAKE SURE TURTLE ISNT SCANNING ITS SELF
            {
                distanceToPotentialFlock = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.getPositionX()-t.getPositionX()),2 ) + Math.pow((this.getPositionY()-this.getPositionY()),2)); //FIND DISTANCE BETWEEN CURRENT AND SCANNED TURTLE

                if(distanceToPotentialFlock < flockingDistanceLimit) //MAKE SURE THE FOUND TURTLE IS WITHIN RANGE USING THE DISTANCE BETWEEN POINTS METHOD
                {
                    combinedX = combinedX + t.getPositionX(); //FIND SUMMATION OF X POSITIONS
                    combinedY = combinedY + t.getPositionY(); //FIND SUMMATION OF Y POSITIONS
                    numberOfFlockers++; //AS A FLOCKER HAS BEEN FOUND INCREMENT THE NUMBER OF FLOCKERS
                }
            }

            if(numberOfFlockers > 0)
            {                
                averageCombinedX = (combinedX / numberOfFlockers); //FIND AVERAGE X POSITION
                averageCombinedY = (combinedY / numberOfFlockers); //FIND AVERAGE Y POSITION

                int moveToFlock = (int) ((Math.sqrt(Math.pow(averageCombinedX,2 ) + Math.pow(averageCombinedY, 2)))); //CALCULATE DISTANCE TO CENTER OF FLOCKING
                double turnToFlock = (Math.atan(averageCombinedY / averageCombinedX));

                if(turnToFlock < 0)
                {
                    turnToFlock = 360 - (-turnToFlock);
                }  

                this.turn(turnToFlock);
                this.move(5);
                canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
            }
        } 
    }   


    public double getPositionX()
    { 
        return myLocation.getX();
    }

    public double getPositionY()
    {
        return myLocation.getY();        
    }

    public void setPositionX(double x)
    {
        myLocation.setX(this.x);
    }

    public void setPositionY( double y)
    {        
        myLocation.setY(this.y);
    }

    public void putPenUp() 
    {
       this.penDown = false; 
    }

    public void putPenDown() 
    {
        this.penDown = true; 
    }   

    public void turn(double amount) 
    {
       angle = angle + amount; 
    }    

    public void move(int pixels) 
    {
        double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double dx = pixels * Math.sin(radians);
        double dy = pixels * Math.cos(radians);

        CartesianCoordinate oldLocation = myLocation.copy();

        myLocation.add(dx,dy);

        if(penDown)
        {
            canvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(myLocation, oldLocation);
        }
    }

    public void drawTurtle()
    {
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(90);
        this.move(10);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(20);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(20);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(10);
        this.turn(270);   
    }

    public void unDrawTurtle()
    {
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the `Turtule` `update` method look like? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The update method is as follows: public void update(int time)
 {
  randomAngleDouble = Utils.randomDouble();
  secondRandomAngleDouble = Utils.randomDouble();
  randomAngleInt = Utils.randomInt(50);  
  this.move((speed*10/time)); 
  canvas.removeMostRecentLine();

Comment: I didnt think that would paste well, but oh well. I don't think i would be able to provide a runnable way of showing the code as i am currently using 8 classes. thanks for helping. Cheers.